# counting frequencies in a collection of bins

Tags: haskell

I need to count values inbetween values in a list i.e. [135,136,138,140] would count all the numbers between 135-136,136-138,138-140. with the input list [135.2,135.3,137,139] would out put[2,1,1] using type [Float] [Float] [Int]. So far I have:

```
 heightbetween :: Float -> Float -> [Float] -> Int
 heightbetween _ _ [] = 0
 heightbetween n s (x:xs) 
     | (n < x) && (s > x) = 1 + (heightbetween n s xs)
     | otherwise = heightbetween n s xs

  count :: [Float] -> [Float] -> [Int]
  count [] [] = []
  count [x,y] = [(x,y)]
  count (x:y:ys) = (x,y):count (y:ys)

  forEach fun lst = heightbetween op ([],lst)
    where
  op (start,[]) = Nothing
  op (start,a:as) = Just (start++(fun a):as
                        ,(start++[a],as)) 

 forPairs fun lst lst2 = map (map fst) 
                     $ forEach (\(a,b)->(fun a b,b))
                     $ zip lst lst2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `count` looks strange. It should be like this:

```
-- count -> ranges -> data -> [counts]
count :: [Float] -> [Float] -> [Int]
count [] _ = []     -- no ranges given -> empty list 
count [_] _ = []    -- no ranges, but single number -> empty list
count _ [] = []     -- no data given -> empty list
count (x:y:xs) d = 
    (heightbetween x y d) : count (y:xs) d

heightbetween :: Float -> Float -> [Float] -> Int
heightbetween _ _ [] = 0
heightbetween n s (x:xs) 
    | (n < x) && (s > x) = 1 + (heightbetween n s xs)
    | otherwise = heightbetween n s xs
```

The other lines are obsolete.
Then invoking

```
 count [135,136,138,140]  [135.2,135.3,137,139]
```

gives

```
[2,1,1]
```

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure that your range list is in order....

```
rangePoints =  [135,136,138,140]

orderedRangePoints = sort rangePoints
```

Next, you will find it much easier to work with actual ranges (which you can represent using a 2-tuple `(low,high)`)

```
ranges = zip orderedRangePoints $ tail orderedRangePoints
```

You will need an inRange function (one already exists in Data.Ix, but unfortunately it includes the upperbound, so you can't use it)

```
inRange (low,high) val | val >= low && val < high = True
inRange _ _ = False
```

You will also want to order your input points

```
theData = sort [135.2,135.3,137,139]
```

With all of this out of the way, the binCount function is easy to write.

```
binCount'::[(Float, Float)]->[Float]->[Int]
binCount' [] [] = []
binCount' (range:rest) vals = 
      length valsInRange:binCount' rest valsAboveRange
      where
          (valsInRange, valsAboveRange) = span (`inRange` range) vals
```

Notice, that I defined a function called `binCount'`, not `binCount`.  I did this, because I consider this an unsafe function, because it only works on ordered ranges and values....  You should finalize this by writing a safer `binCount` function, which puts all of the stuff above in its where clause.  You should probably add all the types and some error checking also (what happens if a value is outside of all ranges?).

Comment: @Eugene Sh. how would i also count the values greater than 140 and lower than 135? It sould be sim[ple from here on in but I keep gettint the same error